# JDBC Connection Error to Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, url, jdbc

I'm trying to establish a connection from Java to Oracle DB. (My DB is in another machine)

The form of URL as i know is like : String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portnumber:sid";

And here is my Java code to establish a connection:

```
package net.metric.action;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
    try{
           DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            //CONNECT TO DB
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@252.112.60.47:1521:XE";
            System.out.println(url);

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"EXT02501231","Tellcom30");
              conn.setAutoCommit(false);
               Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("OK");

              /* ResultSet rset =
                    stmt.executeQuery("select * from SBO_AUDIT_NEW.AUDIT_EVENT");
               while (rset.next()) {
                    System.out.println (rset.getString(1));
               }
               stmt.close();
               System.out.println ("Ok.");*/


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

I'm getting this error :

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

What am I doing wrong? Any answer would be appreciated.. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed your oracle DB is set up to accept connections from outside the localhost?

Comment: I hope the user and password in your example are fake :-)

Comment: ping you remote host and check if it accepts remote connection and why you need to register the driver twice?

Comment: Have you try the connection string you have in your tnsnames.ora file.
Like String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=
   (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=prodHost)))"

Comment: What is the output if you do `tnsping SILAHTAR` or `tnsping XE`? Execute from the same machine where you are getting JDBC errors.

Comment: make sure your etc/hosts file has the machine in it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three ways to write to a jdbc url.

If you are connecting with service name you should put / before service name

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service_name    --- In your case this is how you need the url
```

if you are connecting with sid you should put : before sid

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid
```

or use the description in your tns file after @

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=....)
```

BUT non of them are the cause for your problem. This error is not an SQLException. It is a TCP/IP connection exception. That means you somehow can not reach the machine.

Are you able to connect to the database with another client ? I see you are using TOAD. Are you able to connect with toad ? You need to make sure you can reach the server.

Try pinging to the machine on command line

```
 ping 85.29.60.47
```

if you get response back then try telnet on the port

```
telnet 85.29.60.47 1521  -- You must have a telnet client installed to do that.
```

You will probably see either ping or telnet fails. So it is probably a firewall issue. What you need to do is to contact network administrators about the problem then.

Comment: I am not able to ping 85.29.60.47 from my machine and the toad is not executing on the machine that I have Oracle DB. I guess it is about firewall issue as you mentioned. Thanks a lot @gomyes your answer was so clear to me :)